# Eclipse, defined all classes within main program. After spliting to seperate class files program does not work

Tags: java, class

I am using eclipse to develop my program. I initially did not think I was going to keep buildign this program so I made all the classes within one main class, it then became a wall of text so I decided to split them into seperate classes.

But now it seems they cannot access the fields in the main program now that they are in their own class file. Do I need to add some modifier such as C++'s **friend class**?

I get a NullPointerException on the line that says error. I am also confused to because when writing that line in the IDE it will auto complete to say that it can I guess "see" the option to call a.doSomething() but when it comes to running it, it thinks that it is null.

Example Code: (This is a representation of the error I am running into, I cannot post the entire code because of how large it is)

```
// Suppose AObject is an object that does something and causes no errors.


// BEFORE SPLITING
public class myApp
{
    static myApp app = null;
    AObject a = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        a = new AObject();
        app = new CLUtilCompact();
    }

    public myApp() 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater
        (
            new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    JFrame mainscreen = new JFrame();
                    myPanel myP = new myPanel();
                    mainscreen.add(myP);
                    mainscreen.setVisible(true);
                }
            };
        )
    }
    public class myPanel
    {
        public myPanel()
        {
            a.doSomething();  // Works fine
        }
    }
}

// AFTER SPLIT TO CLASS FILES
public class myApp
{
    static myApp app = null;
    AObject a = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        a = new AObject();
        app = new CLUtilCompact();
    }

    public myApp() 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater
        (
            new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    JFrame mainscreen = new JFrame();
                    myPanel myP = new myPanel(this);
                    mainscreen.add(myP);
                    mainscreen.setVisible(true);
                }
            };
        )
    }
}
// SEPERATE CLASS
public class myPanel
{
    myApp theApp = null;
    public myPanel(myApp arg)
    {
        theApp = arg;
        theApp.a.doSomething();  // Error
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a compile error or runtime error? btw, this code can't possibly work, it has infinite recursion in mainclass() constructor.

Comment: Edited code, please re-review.

Comment: This code is quite convoluted and, if I understand you correctly, is not even the code in which you have an error.  I suggest that you take your real code or a copy of it and start cutting stuff out that is not related to your problem, so that we can see a reduced version of your real code that illustrates your problem.  Include what error message you get and how you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about qualifiers for fields in classes: public, protected, private, and "package protected".

Without a qualifier, the field is actually "package protected", and a class in the same package should be able to access it as you have specified.  If it is in a different package, then it would give you a compile-time error saying it did not recognize the field in the other class.

But this is guesswork, because you haven't given us real code, you haven't told us what the error is, and you haven't told us what you've tried.

rc

Comment: Changed question, please re-review.